# Android: Show a Canvas on a View

Tags: android, canvas

I am trying to create a `Canvas`, draw stuff on it, and then show it on a `View`. My code below runs with no errors, but the `Canvas` doesn't show. All I see is a blank, black screen.

I know there are other ways to do this example, but what I am actually trying to do is draw a bunch of stuff on the `Canvas`, show it, draw more stuff on the `Canvas`, show it, etc....

I am very new to Android. I have tried to look, but haven't been able to find any simple solution [simple for me :)]

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        //Get screen size. THIS WORKS; when I log the output it's correct.
        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);

        //Create Canvas.
        Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(size.x, size.y, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bmp); 
        /*
        I know the Canvas is created, because when I call
            canvas.getWidth() and canvas.getHeight()
        I get the correct pixel size of the device; i.e.
        (same as size.x and size.y respectively).
        */

        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        //Draw other stuff on the canvas.
        View v = findViewById(R.id.view);
        v.draw(canvas);
        /*
        I know v is working because when I call
            v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        The whole screen is red.
        */
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="${relativePackage}.${activityClass}" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/view" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't know if this is necessary, but just in case:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="main.stupidbird"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="17"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:persistent="true">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going about it the wrong way.

I believe what you are going for is to extend View and do your drawing in the onDraw().

https://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/custom-drawing.html

If it isn't, and you really just want to draw an image, why not take the bitmap the canvas drew to and put it in an imageview?

finally, you can go here, and see a similar question answered of you really want to do it this way.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16606144/1116836